# (Almost) every time I unplug my headphone, the Voice Command app opens. How to make it stop?

Tags: voice-command, headphone-jack, intents

This happens frequently enough to make me believe the unplugging has some influence on it, but it doesn't happen all the time, so I'm not quite sure...

I can think of two options to find out who's responsible:

- Detect which apps/services are launching (not receiving!) the [Voice Command intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
- Detect which apps/services can handle the [Action Headset Plug intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG), since that seems to be causing all the trouble;

the idea being that once I find out who is screwing up, I can take the necessary steps to solve the issue.

Does anybody know of an app which can help me? Hopefully without needing to root my device? I own a Motorola Milestone 2, with standard-issue Android 2.3.6.

Capturing the log (with LogCollector) just after reproducing the problem yields (after a LOT of stuff):

```
11-21 15:23:57.014 W/Vold    ( 1209): Ignoring unknown switch 'No Device'
11-21 15:23:57.030 D/MediaButtonSettingReceiver(22525): onReceive: ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON but user has disabled us
11-21 15:23:57.030 V/HeadsetObserver( 1376): Headset UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=switch, SWITCH_STATE=0, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/switch/h2w, SEQNUM=10716, ACTION=change, SWITCH_NAME=No Device}
11-21 15:23:57.061 I/ActivityManager( 1376): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp/.VSuiteStartSession } from pid 1459
11-21 15:23:57.069 D/LockPlayer(22525): ONPAUSE
11-21 15:23:57.077 V/LockPlayer(22525): Current heap: 10032928/10240000
11-21 15:23:57.093 I/ActivityManager( 1376): Start proc com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp for activity com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp/.VSuiteStartSession: pid=23777 uid=10033 gids={3001, 3002, 3003}
```

Elixir reveals Cell broadcast (`com.android.phone`) as the process with pid 1459.

Well, crap. Still at a loss...

Comment: You don't have Turntable.fm installed, do you? When I had that app I had all kinds of "interesting" things going on when unplugging headphones, connecting to power, and so on.

Comment: Your headphones could short out the headphone jack for a second, making the phone think you press a button on the headset... is there any difference on whether you disconnect the headphones quickly or slowly?

Comment: @AlEverett Nope, no Turntable.fm... I have this inkling that [Plug in Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.launcher.plugin) may be the source of my problems, but I uninstalled that a long time ago... But now I'm just guessing.

Comment: @onik Wow, I wouldn't have thought of that :) I honestly haven't being paying attention, but I seem to recall it happening both when I yank it out and when I remove it gently.

Comment: @HumbertoAnjos I'd suggest trying with another pair of headphones if possible, but this is just a gut feeling, so I won't post it as an answer, at least not yet :)

Comment: @onik It's my second pair of headphones, and this still happens. I haven't been able to repro this now (neither with other headphones or my own), so I'll try later.

Comment: Well, I installed [Headset Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idunnolol.headsetblocker), and the problem hasn't happened since. That doesn't mean much, since it is intermittent, but a man can hope :)